# Killing daemon and closing port without ability to use 'lsof'

Tags: linux, port, daemon

I have an application that spits out the time when it is requested from a client. I don't have permissions to use port 13, so I put it on a really high-numbered port. Now I can't kill that port, and I can't use the port for anything else. How do I find the daemon to kill it (ps -ef doesn't show it) and close the port? I cannot use 'lsof' because I'm using Redhat.

Comment: _"I cannot use 'lsof' because I'm using Redhat"_ – lsof has been ported to a dozen different operating systems and every single Linux distro; I'm sure it's available for Red Hat.

Comment: Look for `lsof` in **`/usr/sbin`**.

Comment: Can you use `netstat -p`?

Comment: Every relatively recent Red Hat comes with lsof(1). In case you're trimmed down your package selection and don't have it installed, install it with yum(1).

Answer (score 1):

> Now I can't kill that port, and I can't use the port for anything else. How do I find the daemon to kill it (`ps -ef` doesn't show it) and close the port? I cannot use `lsof` because I'm using Redhat.

Others have pointed out one of the errors in the above.  A second error is that one cannot "kill" ports.  Ports are not processes.  A third error is the assumption that you have some secret magic process that `ps -e` won't show to you.  If there's no process listed, then barring some obscure corner cases *there's no process*.  A fourth error, ironically perhaps the most major one, is assuming that a connection to the port is still open in the first place.

A far more mundane explanation, that fits the reported behaviour without needing magically invisible processes, is that the process exited, but nothing can yet bind to the port because the TCP connection is still in `TIME_WAIT`.  The `-o` option to `netstat` is your friend.  As indeed is the `-p` option.

SuperUser is not the right place to ask about how one writes such daemons, by the way.  And StackOverflow, which is, addresses this and related questions over and over again.

### Further reading

- Vic Metcalfe, Andrew Gierth, et al (1998-05-21). ["Writing Server Applications (TCP/SOCK_STREAM)"](http://www.minek.com/files/sock-faq/unix-socket-faq-4.html). *Programming UNIX Sockets in C — Frequently Asked Questions*.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/

Comment: While it's true that Stack Overflow is the place to ask about _writing_ programs, this question (and others about _using_ them) is perfectly suited for Super User (and, indeed, would be _off topic_ on SO).

Comment: It you pay attention to the close votes on the question, Blacklight Shining, you'll see that no-one has said otherwise.  But if you pay _even closer attention still_ you'll see that [the questioner is trying to write programs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924352/).